# Why can't I use 'use' in non-anonymous functions?

Tags: php, recursion, closures

I'm trying to create a path from an array of parent-child elements.

The idea was to write a recursive function, which fills up an array with all the elements the path contains in order.

My problem is with closure in PHP:

To get my recursive function to work, I had to define several variables in the global scope.

This is how it looks like:

```
global $breadcrumbs;
$breadcrumbs = array();
function buildBreadcrumbs($elements, $parentID){
    global $siteroot;
    global $breadcrumbs;
    global $navigation;
    if($siteroot['id'] === $parentID){
        $nav = array_values($navigation);
        array_unshift($breadcrumbs, array('label' => 'Start', 'id' => $nav[0]['id']));
    } else {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if ($element['id'] === $parentID) {
                array_unshift($breadcrumbs, array('label' => $element['navlabel'], 'id' => $element['id']));
                buildBreadcrumbs($elements, $element['parent'][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using the 'use' keyword instead of globals in this way:

```
function buildBreadcrumbs($elements, $parentID) use($siteroot, $breadcrumbs, $navigation){
        if($siteroot['id'] === $parentID){
            $nav = array_values($navigation);
            array_unshift($breadcrumbs, array('label' => 'Start', 'id' => $nav[0]['id']));
        } else {
            foreach ($elements as $element) {
                if ($element['id'] === $parentID) {
                    array_unshift($breadcrumbs, array('label' => $element['navlabel'], 'id' => $element['id']));
                    buildBreadcrumbs($elements, $element['parent'][0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this gives me syntax error:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting '{'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Why does `$breadcrumbs` have to be global in the first place so the function can use it?

Comment: the function is local to itself, it doesn't have access to variables outside of it, unless you choose to add a parameter to it. That's why it doesn't have access to `$breadcrumbs` - because it's out of scope

Comment: Why aren't you passing the vars into the function?

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are all only used in this class, you can use the $this keyword.

Example:

```
private $breadcrumbs = array();
private $siteroot;
private $navigation;

function buildBreadcrumbs($elements, $parentID){
    if($this->siteroot['id'] === $parentID){
        $nav = array_values($this->navigation);
        array_unshift($this->breadcrumbs, array('label' => 'Start', 'id' => $nav[0]['id']));
    } else {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if ($element['id'] === $parentID) {
                array_unshift($this->breadcrumbs, array('label' => $element['navlabel'], 'id' => $element['id']));
                buildBreadcrumbs($elements, $element['parent'][0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If they are truly global variables then you have to use them as global. Or create a function after this that updates your global variables with your class variables (which you updated with the $this keyword.)

Comment: OP isn't using classes.

Answer (score 0):

With anonymous functions, you aren't importing variables from the global scope, you're importing variables from the parent scope.

A big distinction would be:

```
$global = 123;
function parent() {
   $parent = 123;
   $closure = function() use ($parent, $global) {
      // $global won't exist, but $parent will.
   }
}
```

A named function doesn't have the same "parent" scope as closures.

> Inheriting variables from the parent scope is not the same as using
>   global variables. Global variables exist in the global scope, which is
>   the same no matter what function is executing. The parent scope of a
>   closure is the function in which the closure was declared

See example #4 here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php